# IVR Chatbot using MS Composer

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

I'm creating an IVR chatbot using MS composer, wherein a particular dialog I need to take 16 digits(Card Number) user input either both by voice or by keypad. In composer, I created a user input activity to take the input but it was breaking for the first number, for example, my card number is 9876543210123456 as soon as I typed 9 or spoke out 9 it is taking that particular only 9 as input and validating it, instead of all 16 digits.

Can anyone please help me solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of input are you using? If using a number input, it probably won't accept the entire phone number.

Comment: @AP01 I'm using text Input

Comment: Text input in composer is fairly straightforward, as the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-ask-for-user-input?tabs=v2x) show. What are you doing specifically in your bot?

Comment: @AP01, I mean I'm collecting data from mobile keypad [In composer I was prompting the user (Ask a question>> Text)]

Comment: I don't think composer is set up for accepting DTMF input in this manner. I've only seen examples of single digits (press 1 for this, 2 for that). In addition, on github in the botframework-telephony project, there is an example on  [collecting DTMF input](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-telephony/issues/30) but it is implemented in C# not in Composer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Composer is currently setup to collect DTMF digits and aggregate them into a number. I've only seen composer examples with DTMF navigation (single digits, press 1 for this, press 2 for that).

Also, I think you may be conflating two issues. I have implemented a composer bot using speech rec that collects a string of digits (say a zip code or credit card) into a text field. This works fine with a text chatbot or a phone call using speech recognition.

But you cannot currently also take DTMF input in the same block. As you describe, pressing a DTMF key in text prompt for the zip code completes after the first DTMF keypress. Subsequent validation rejects the reply as too short. The prompt for text block only ever collects one DTMF digit. In my experience.

There are ways around this in code but not in Composer out of the box to my knowledge.